# How can I stop auto-replying to my email when using google-script?

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I have made a script to automatically reply when I'm outside of working hours.
The sender receive one message from me, as expected. However, I am getting an email with the same content every minute, until I actually read the customer email.

I do not want to mark the email as read until I actually read it.

Is there a solution of stopping sending these emails?
Thank you!

[image: The inbox on my email]

[image: The trigger configuration]

```js
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5; // if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
var wkday = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0]; // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su

  var wkMessage = "Buna ziua!\n\nMultumim pentru email!\n\nProgramul de lucru este de luni pana vineri, intre 8:00 - 16:30.\nIn fiecare luna, programul de lucru pentru ziua de vineri din prima si ultima saptamana este in intervalul orar 8:00 - 14:00.\n\nMultumim!"
  var progMessage= "Buna ziua!\n\nMultumim pentru email!\n\nVa vom raspunde imediat.\n\nMultumim!"
 
  var date = new Date();  
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  if (wkday.indexOf(day) == 6 || wkday.indexOf(day) == 0 || (day == 5 && hour >= 14)) { 
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(wkMessage);
    }
  }
  else if (wkday.indexOf(day) > 0 && wkday.indexOf(day) < 6 && (hour >=8 && hour <= 17)) { 
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(progMessage);
    }
  }
  else if (hour < 8 || (hour >= 16 && minutes >= 30)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(wkMessage.bold());
    }
  }
  
}
function doGet() {
 return ContentService.createTextOutput("");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interval value is still 5, thus you are receiving the same unread thread every minute for 5 minutes.

You need to change this depending on the frequency of the trigger as per comment:

```
var interval = 1; // if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
```